# Power Query column based on conditionals

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, conditional-statements, powerquery

Hey guys new to Power BI here and I am having some trouble creating a column based on conditionals in Power Query.

I am trying to do something like if the previous letter was A,B,or C and the current letter is E,F,or G mark True, else False.

My code looks like this so far:

Custom Column =

IF List.Contains({“A”, “B”,”C”}), [PrevLetter]

AND list.Contains({“E”, “F”, ”G”}) , [Letters]

THEN “TRUE”

ELSE “FALSE”

Output would be so something like:

| PrevLetter | Letter | CustomColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | F | True |
| X | M | False |
| B | E | True |
| C | F | True |

Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: I actually figured it out! Looks like this Custom Column =

if List.Contains({“A”, “B”,”C”}), [PrevLetter]

and list.Contains({“E”, “F”, ”G”}) , [Letters]

then “TRUE”

else “FALSE”

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on if you are looking for a letter within a word, or if that letter represents the entire text, but for your example, one answer could be

```
= if Text.PositionOfAny([PrevLetter], {"A", "B","C"})+Text.PositionOfAny([Letter], {"E", "F","G"})=0 then true else false
```

or if you want to plan around nulls

```
= try if Text.PositionOfAny([PrevLetter], {"A", "B","C"})+Text.PositionOfAny([Letter], {"E", "F","G"})=0 then true else false otherwise false
```

or

```
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if List.ContainsAny({[PrevLetter]},{"A","B","C"}) and List.ContainsAny({[Letter]},{"D","E","F"}) then true else false  )
```